# Cannot Create TabLayout in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-tabhost

I am trying to create a TabLayout in XML as a user profile page. Essentially, I want to display text on 3 separate tabs, and the text will update based on dynamic data in Firebase. Here is my code that I have, and it is not rendering my first tab. I am essentially aiming for the design below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabcontent">

    <TabHost android:id="@+id/tab_host"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TEST"/>
                </TabWidget>
    </TabHost>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Exception raised during rendering: TabHost requires a FrameLayout with
>   id "android:id/tabcontent".

That means you should use FrameLayout inside the TabHost, with the above id

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new **android.support.design.widget.TabLayout**, simple and easy to use. Here is a simple example, Click TabItem to switch pages.

Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="table 1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="table 2"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="table 3"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<ViewAnimator
    android:id="@+id/main_viewanimator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button_pip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/pip_mode"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST"/>
</ViewAnimator>
```

Java Code

```
mViewAnimator = findViewById(R.id.main_viewanimator);
mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_tablayout);
mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(mTabListen);

private final TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener mTabListen = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                mViewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(0);
                break;

            case 1:
                mViewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(1);
                break;

            case 2:
                mViewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(2);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
};
```

Snapshot
[image]

Comment: while I think your answer may work, I am essentially using the tabs as XML and am going to place dynamic text inside the tabs (it will update based on interaction with Firebase). I do not actually need the recylerview feature, the tabs are merely display only similar to the profile screen.